# About the setting of the book "Representations of Semisimple Lie Algebras in the BGG Category $\mathcal{O}$"

Tags: lie-algebras

I would like to ask about the setting of the book **"Representations of Semisimple Lie Algebras in the BGG Category $\mathcal{O}$"** by Humphreys. I would like to know whether the semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite dimensional or not. I search the book and did not find any assumption about the semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ being finite dimensional. However, the book mentions root space decomposition of $\mathfrak{g}$, which depends on the finite dimensionality of $\mathfrak{g}$ by Humphreys' other book **"Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory"**. Also a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ is mentioned to be finite dimensional on p.1 of **"Representations of Semisimple Lie Algebras in the BGG Category $\mathcal{O}$"**.

**My questions:**

1. Is the semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ finite dimensional?
2. If $\mathfrak{g}$ is not assumed to be finite dimensional, do we still have the root space decomposition of complex semisimple Lie algebra with respect to a Cartan subalgebra?
3. If $\mathfrak{g}$ is not assumed to be finite dimensional, does the root space decomposition imply that any complex semisimple Lie algebra with a Cartan subalgebra is finite dimensional?
4. If $\mathfrak{g}$ is not assumed to be finite dimensional, how do we prove $\mathfrak{h}$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: Yes, the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite dimensional.   I'm sorry if this traditional setting isn't clear enough, but beyond this is mainly the Kac-Moody case which is not usually viewed as "semisimple".

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Comment: By the way, I would like to know does $\mathfrak{g}$ is complex semisimple Lie algebra imply $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite dimensional by the root space decomposition or do people just omit the words "finite dimensional" when assuming $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite dimensional complex semisimple since it is a traditional setting?

Answer (score 4):

1. In the book, $\mathfrak{g}$ is always assumed to be finite-dimensional.  (I believe that this is explicitly stated in the first chapter of the book.)
2. Depending on $\mathfrak{g}$ and on the definition of Cartan subalgebras in the infinite-dimensional setting, you may have an infinite-dimensional semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ such that, with respect to $\mathfrak{h}$, the root-space decomposition of $\mathfrak{g}$ exists.  You can look at something like ***[root-reductive Lie algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603004)***.
3. See my answer to 2.
4. Also see my answer to 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But I really cannot find out the assumption $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite dimensional throughout the book by manually searching the word "finite". I just find out some sentences implicitly suggest that $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite dimensional. e.g. p.36 (the last sentence) and p.259 (the last sentence in Section 13.6). If you can find it out, please let me know.

Comment: Well, isn't a semisimple lie algebra just a (finite) direct sum of simple Lie algebras, each of which is finite dimensional.